# Finding property differences in two lists

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Let's say I have two lists.

We KNOW that the number of items in the list is the same, and that ID's match.

BUT, one or more of the properties (other than the ID) may have changed.  In this case, two of the quantities changed:

```
List1
---------
{
    ItemId: 1
    Quantity: 10
}
{
    ItemId: 2
    Quantity: 12
}
{
    ItemId: 3
    Quantity: 1
}
```

And then a nearly identical list of matching items...

```
List2
---------
{
    ItemId: 1
    Quantity: 10
}
{
    ItemId: 2
    Quantity: 3
}
{
    ItemId: 5
    Quantity: 1
}
```

Other than looping over each of them and comparing the Quantity property, is there a way to compare the two lists, find the ID's where a change has occurred, and then call an Update method only on the changed items?

In other words, I am just trying to avoid looping over each list.

Comment: Use `GroupBy` to find duplicates, then filter them out?

Comment: Any solution that will come up here will be iterating behind the scene...

Comment: ok, that's what I wondered.  So is there is no build-in delta method that doesn't iterate. (sigh)  I may have to rethink this all together.

Comment: @Eris -- that might be the best solution

Comment: If you are saying that `List1[i].ItemId == List2[i].ItemId` then one loop will be sufficient and easy to understand. If the data came from a database, perhaps you could modify the query used to obtain the data.

Comment: I agree with E-Bat - there are a lot of solutions, but they will all implement at least one loop behind the scenes, since you have inspect each element at some point.  The `Except` extension is really nice for this (if you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`).  It would run in O(n+m), or 2n in your case.

Comment: Could you show the bigger picture? Why do you want this? If you use an ORM you can probably leave this to its change tracking mechanism.

Comment: The IDs do not match in your example.  List 1 has IDs 1, 2, and 3, while list 2 has 1, 2, and 5.  If you are certain that the IDs DO match then `Zip` will be faster than a join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution 1 using a join:

```
var diffs = List1
  .Join(List2, r2=>r2.ItemId, r1=>r1.ItemId, (r1,r2)=> new { r1, r2 })
  .Where(r=> r.r1.Quantity != l.r2.Quantity);
```

Solution 2 using except (if the items are comparable):

```
var diffs = List1.Except(List2);
```

Solution 3 using [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ):

```
var diffs = List1.ExceptBy(List2, e=> new {e.ItemId, e.Quantity});
```